# MongoDB Conditional Sum of Array Elements for a collection of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following MongoDB collection of documents, each containing a field called "history", which contains an array of sub-documents with fields "date" and "points".

```
[{
    history: [{
        date: "2019-20-20",
        points: 1,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-21",
        points: 1,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-22",
        points: 1,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-23",
        points: 1,
    }],
}, {
    history: [{
        date: "2019-20-20",
        points: 1,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-21",
        points: 2,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-22",
        points: 3,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-23",
        points: 4,
    }],
}]
```

**I'm not sure what is the best way to construct a query that produces the below output. For the following example, the date range (inclusive) is "2019-20-21" to "2019-20-22". "totalPoints" is a new field, which contains the sum of all the points in the "history" field across that date range.**

```
[{
    history: [{
        date: "2019-20-20",
        points: 1,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-21",
        points: 1,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-22",
        points: 1,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-23",
        points: 1,
    }],
    totalPoints: 2,
}, {
    history: [{
        date: "2019-20-20",
        points: 1,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-21",
        points: 2,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-22",
        points: 3,
    }, {
        date: "2019-20-23",
        points: 4,
    }],
    totalPoints: 5,
}]
```

Below is a general idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
User.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        totalPoints: { $sum: points in "history" field if date range between "2019-20-21" and "2019-20-22" } ,
    }
}]);
```

The reason I want to create a new "totalPoints" field is because eventually I want to sort via the "totalPoints" field.

Comment: **Note:** If you want to sort by "calculated" value, MongoDB performance will be *poor* because of `top-k` sort algorithm

Comment: @Valijon Do you have any tips on how I can improve the performance of my query if I'm sorting on a calculated value?

Comment: You need to do a benchmarking, MongoDb doesn't provide any solution for [such situation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#restrictions). Consider sorting outside of MongoDB with "Heap search" described [here](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/?id=122)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single pipeline, you can combine [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) to get the sum as follows:

```
var startDate = "2019-20-21";
var endDate = "2019-20-22";
User.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { 
        "totalPoints": {
            "$reduce": {
                "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$history",
                        "as": "el",
                        "cond": {
                            "$and": [
                                { "$gte": ["$$el.date", startDate] },
                                { "$lte": ["$$el.date", endDate ] },
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "initialValue": 0,
                "in": { "$add": [ "$$value", "$$this.points" ] }
            }
        }
    } }
]);
```

---

Another alternative is having two pipeline stages where you start your aggregation with a filtered array which contains only the elements that match the date range query. Combine [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields) with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) for this and your filter condition uses the conditional operator [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/and/) with the comparison operators [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/) and [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lte/). The following pipeline shows this:

```
{ "$addFields": { 
    "totalPoints": {
        "$filter": {
            "input": "$history",
            "cond": {
                "$and": [
                    { "$gte": ["$$this.date", "2019-20-21"] },
                    { "$lte": ["$$this.date", "2019-20-22"] },
                ]
            }
        }
    }
} },
```

On getting the filtered array you can then get the sum easily in the next pipeline with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/), so your complete pipeline becomes

```
var startDate = "2019-20-21";
var endDate = "2019-20-22";
User.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": { 
        "totalPoints": {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$history",
                "cond": {
                    "$and": [
                        { "$gte": ["$$this.date", startDate] },
                        { "$lte": ["$$this.date", endDate ] },
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    } },
    { "$addFields": { 
        "totalPoints": { "$sum": "$totalPoints.points" }
    } }
])
```

---

Comment: Thanks for providing both approaches - would it be correct to say that the single pipeline approach is more performant than the alternative approach you've provided?

Comment: Correct, a single pipeline is better though I believe in the above scenario the performance delta is negligible. What would greatly improve the performance would be to reduce the amount of data passing through the pipeline, i.e. do an initial pipeline stage`$match` with the above date range query